# Excel VBA or formula to copy value of multiple ActiveX text box to adjacent cells

Tags: excel, textbox, copy-paste, vba

I have received a workbook with a whole lot of ActiveX text boxes in columns with values I need to use. Is there a way to get those values and put them in the column to the right of each box location?

They are locked and "move with cells". They appear in the selection pane as "HTMLText nnn". There is one value in each text box.

I have tried this from Kutools (thank you to them, [the page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4047-excel-convert-textbox-to-cell.html)), it looks like it should work, but nothing happens (no values copied, no boxes deleted):

```
Sub TextboxesToCell_Kutools()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xCol As Long
    Dim xTxtBox As TextBox
     
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select a cell):", "Kutools for Excel", _
        ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal, , , , , 8)
    xRow = xRg.Row
    xCol = xRg.Column
     
    For Each xTxtBox In ActiveSheet.TextBoxes
        Cells(xRow, xCol).Value = xTxtBox.text
        xTxtBox.Delete
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Next
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
    Sub H___CopyFormsHTMLBoxToSameCell()
'https://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/169760-Text-box-value-from-a-web-page-copy-and-paste (modified)

Dim OLEObj As OLEObject 'from the control toolbox toolbar
Dim DestCell As Range
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet

With wks
    For Each OLEObj In .OLEObjects
        If TypeOf OLEObj.Object Is msforms.TextBox Then
            Set DestCell = OLEObj.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 0)
            DestCell.Value = OLEObj.Object.Value
             OLEObj.Delete 'vp added
'    ActiveCell.Activate doesnt center cell!

        End If
    Next OLEObj
End With

MsgBox "Done. Home, find, selection pane check for other shapes; f5, objects, Ctrl-click unselect pictures, delete."

End Sub
```